# Interstitial Ad Interaction Issue

Tags: ios, ipad, iad

I'm trying to add full page interstitial ads to my app for the first time. All seems to work fine, except that I'm getting unexpected behavior. Referring to figure 3-3 in [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Full-ScreenAdvertisements/Full-ScreenAdvertisements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH5-SW1), here's what's going on.

The object is created, as expected. Because I don't want the app interrupted, I'm not using `interstitialAdDidLoad:`. Instead, I am checking the `loaded` property at a time that is convenient to display an ad. This takes care of the second and third items in the diagram. The fourth item in the diagram states "User touches ad". That's where my problem comes in.

My app contains a main view (`self.mainView') that is always orthogonal to the user and fills the full screen. To present the ad, I've added a scroll view to it, and presented the ad in this scroll view. Fine so far, except that`self.mainView` has gesture recognizers attached to it. So they get triggered. This surprises me, because I thought the ad view controller would have taken over. Does this happen because the ad's VC hasn't taken over yet?

Any recommendations on how to prevent the `self.mainView`'s gesture recognizers from acting on a touch to the ad? Possible solutions could be changing all my gesture recognizer code to test for this condition, creating a view as a sibling of `self.mainView` in which to present the ad, removing the gesture recognizers or somehow disabling them, or perhaps something else. Or should I just make the scroll view in which to present the ad a subview of `self.view`?

P.S. I tried this last item, but it didn't work.

Comment: I think I resolved this by changing the frame of the view with the gesture recognizers to be off screen, restoring the original frame when the ad finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by disabling the gesture recognizers:

```
self.tap.enabled = NO;
self.pan.enabled = NO;
self.doubleTap.enabled = NO;
self.doublePan.enabled = NO;
self.pinch.enabled = NO;
```

These were turned back on in

```
interstitialAdDidUnload:interstitialAd
```

and

```
interstitialAdActionDidFinish:interstitialAd
```